# The mechanic behind the return function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, return

Can someone explain to me thoroughly what return does in JavaScript? I'am fairly new to JavaScript and I just can't seem to wrap my head around the return function. I'm sorta a perfectionist so, what purpose does it serve? What's the difference of using it in your function - versus not?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not understand what `return` does **in Javascript**, or in *any* language (because it's pretty much the same everywhere)? What exactly *do* you understand about it and what exactly is confusing you? How low can you go? Err, how deep does the answer need to be? Memory allocation, stack, registers? Or just userland logic?

Comment: I'm learning JavaScript from Codecademy and it's a first. Never had a return function in HTML or CSS. The answer doesn't have to be in depth, as long as it explains it. Only know that it 'returns' something and holds onto it until you mke another command?

Comment: [ES5: return statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.9). Maybe you better get familiar with [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) too.

Answer (score 1):

It returns something, and it's that simple, the docs just state

> Specifies the value to be returned by a function

[**MDN Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

```
function test() {
    return 'stuff';
}

var variabel = test(); // returns "stuff"
```

If a return value is not specified, all functions return `undefined` by default

Comment: With one exception to the last sentence: If a function is called with `new` operator, it returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

Functions receive *input* as parameters and produce *output* in the form of return values.

```
var foo = Math.max(1, 2);
```

`Math.max` is the *function*, `1` and `2` are its *input parameters*, and the *return value* is being assigned to `foo`. This should be clear so far, I hope.

When you're writing your own functions, you use `return` to, well, return a value back to the caller of the function, to produce *output*:

```
function myMax(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

var foo = myMax(1, 2);
```

This does basically the same as the above `Math.max` example, but is revealing the inner workings of it. The variable `foo` will hold the value `2`.

As soon as `return` is invoked, the function ends. E.g.:

```
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
    alert('baz');
}
```

That function will never alert "Baz", it is always returning the value 'bar' back to the caller before then and thereby ends.